# Specific case about fragment restoration

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments

The problem is that after I put the app in the background fragment(s) are destroyed, and then when I bring the app back to the foreground it recreates old fragments and according to the app, logic creates additional fragment(s).

I'll explain precisely, in order to check app behavior in case of low memory I enabled in the dev options `Don't keep activity`, so it means that each time I put the app in the background activities will be destroyed and once I bring the app on foreground state will be recreated.

Ok, now about my app architecture, first of all, it navigates with the navigation component `NavHostFragment` secondly it has an activity that consists of a fragment that has `tablayout` with `viewpager`. Tablayout has 2 tabs where each tab is the fragment itself. So, `Activity -> fragment -> tablayout -> 2 more fragments`.

Here according to the logs, you can see that after the UI was created I have 2 PlanFragment then I put the app in the background, as a result, these fragments get `onDestroy` event, it is ok, however, after trying to bring the app back to the foreground it recreates 2 PlanFragment (without calling newInstance method) and then (according to the logic) newInstance method being called and 2 more PlanFragment created as a result I have 4 PlanFragment fragments.

```
=== start create UI ===
43.583  E  AuthActivity onCreate: 186118056
43.630  E  AuthPackageSelectionFragment onCreate: 197020657, parent: NavHostFragment{88ff3d6} (77945dff-a9c2-4f9f-8e11-8218dbd604bf id=0x7f0a050d)
43.798  E  create tablyout fragments AuthPackageSelectionFragment onCreate: 197020657
43.799  E  newInstance PlanFragment 
43.799  E  newInstance PlanFragment 
43.825  E  PlanFragment onCreate: 95398784
43.990  E  PlanFragment onCreate: 205178621
=== UI created ===
=== put app in the background ===
08.787  E  AuthActivity onDestroy: 186118056
08.789  E  PlanFragment onDestroy: 95398784
08.790  E  PlanFragment onDestroy: 205178621
08.801  E  AuthPackageSelectionFragment onDestroy: 197020657, parent: NavHostFragment{88ff3d6} (77945dff-a9c2-4f9f-8e11-8218dbd604bf id=0x7f0a050d)
=== app in the background ===
=== bring app back to foregraund ===
19.757  E  AuthPackageSelectionFragment onCreate: 141365020, parent: NavHostFragment{cb22725} (77945dff-a9c2-4f9f-8e11-8218dbd604bf id=0x7f0a050d)
19.758  E  PlanFragment onCreate: 42083764
19.760  E  PlanFragment onCreate: 129334143
19.761  E  AuthActivity onCreate: 24560031
19.848  E  AuthPackageSelectionFragment onDestroy: 141365020, parent: NavHostFragment{cb22725} (77945dff-a9c2-4f9f-8e11-8218dbd604bf id=0x7f0a050d)
19.850  E  AuthPackageSelectionFragment onCreate: 175242279, parent: NavHostFragment{cb22725} (77945dff-a9c2-4f9f-8e11-8218dbd604bf id=0x7f0a050d)
20.213  E  create tablyout fragments AuthPackageSelectionFragment onCreate: 175242279
20.213  E  newInstance PlanFragment 
20.213  E  newInstance PlanFragment 
20.256  E  PlanFragment onCreate: 96753467
20.380  E  PlanFragment onCreate: 218872921
=== state restored ===
```

As far as I understand one possible solution here is somehow the app shouldn't restore fragments that got `onDestroy` event, so these fragments will only be created according to the logic flow once the parent fragment will be created.

What am I missing here?

**P.S.** If `Don't keep activity` is disabled the app behaves as expected (don't destroys an activity while in the background)

**EDIT**

Fragment that contains TabLayout with ViewPager2

```
open class AuthPackageSelectionFragment : BaseAuthIapFragment() {
    private lateinit var tlPlans: TabLayout
    private lateinit var vpPlans: ViewPager2

...

    private fun initTlForPlans() {
        val adapter = VPPlansAdapter(requireActivity().supportFragmentManager, lifecycle)
        vpPlans.adapter = adapter

        TabLayoutMediator(tlPlans, vpPlans) { tab, position ->
            tab.tag = planFragmentList[position].periodicity
            tab.customView = adapter.getTabView(
                tabLayout = tlPlans,
                text = planFragmentList[position].periodicity.lowercase().replaceFirstChar(Char::titlecase),
                badgeText = planFragmentList[position].badgeText
            )
        }.attach()
    }
    
    ...
    
    private fun subscribe() {
       vm.availablePackage.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { pkgs ->
            planFragmentList = pkgs.map { pkg ->
                    val curFrag: PlanFragment = PlanFragment.newInstance(
                        periodicity = pkg.periodicity,
                        badgeText = pkg.promotionalOverlay,
                        basePlanList = pkg.basePlans ?: listOf(),
                        addonPlanList = pkg.addOns ?: listOf()
                    )

                    curFrag.set(callback = object : PlanFragment.PlanFragmentCallback {
                        override fun doOnSelected(item: List<PlanDescription>) {
                            vm.doOnPlanSelected(item)
                        }
                    })

                    return@map curFrag
                }

                (vpPlans.adapter as VPPlansAdapter).set(tabs = planFragmentList)
            
            ...
          }
          
          ...
```

ViewPager adapter implementation

```
class VPPlansAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle) {
    private var tabs: List<Fragment> = listOf()

    fun set(tabs: List<Fragment>) {
        this.tabs = tabs
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = tabs.size

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment = tabs[position]

    fun getTabView(tabLayout: TabLayout, text: String, badgeText: String?): View =
        LayoutInflater.from(tabLayout.context).inflate(R.layout.auth_tabitem_layout, tabLayout, false)
            .apply {
                (this.findViewById(R.id.tv_tabitem_title) as TextView).text = text
                val tvBadge: TextView = this.findViewById(R.id.tv_badge)

                if (badgeText.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    tvBadge.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                } else {
                    tvBadge.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    tvBadge.text = badgeText
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: both PlanFragment are hosted in the `viewpager`, which is `AuthPackageSelectionFragment`, correct? do you get the same behaviour with the `Don't keep activity` disabled?

Comment: Child fragments, those created as part of a properly set up ViewPager, are also saved and restored, so it would be expected that new instances would not be created. Please include your fragment that contains your ViewPager and your adapter.

Comment: @Stachu that is right. If `Don't keep activity` is disabled the app behaves as expected. Added P.S. in the question as well.

Comment: For one, you're using the wrong FragmentManager (you need to use the `childFragmentManager` - that's why there's a constructor for `FragmentStateAdapter` that takes a Fragment - so you can't mess it up. You did anyways). That `set` method also is not going to work after process death and recreation - where do you call it?